# Force asynctask to exeute every time app is opened

Tags: java, android

I need execute the async task every time the app is opened or executed, because I use this Asyntask to fetch some json data from http and in every app execution Must be fresh data.

Any idea how to force this?

Thanks

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etResponse = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.etResponse);
    etdia = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dia);
    etmes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mes);

    // check if you are connected or not
    if(isConnected()){

    }

    new HttpAsyncTask().execute("URL TO EXECUTE");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the `execute` method in your `onResume()` method.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        new HttpAsyncTask().execute("URL TO EXECUTE");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw you solved your issue. Anyway i'll put here the method for exec the asynctask for EVERY activity of the app:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {

    private String mLastUrl = "";

    public void execAsync(String url) {
        new HttpAsyncTask().execute(url);
        mLastUrl = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        execAsync(mLastUrl);
    }

    //your asynctaskcode
```

On all the other activities you would like to run the asynctask just do this:

```
public class activityName extends myActivity {
```

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: i will just update the answer if i receive the reply!

Comment: Each time activity starts, Clay solved thanks for your message iGio90

Comment: This should be a comment anyway.